# How to use twisted pair as console to manage Cisco devices?

Tags: cisco, cable

Is this possible to use a normal twisted pair cable or roll over to manage Cisco devices through console port? (without any converter to USB)
I tested before a roll over and connected it to Cisco switch but it didn't worked.
is there any kind of software to virtually convert a twisted pair to console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this possible to use a normal twisted pair cable or roll over to manage Cisco devices through console port?

The console port is serial and connects to a host's serial port. You can cut off the 8P8C/RJ-45 and replace by DB9:

```
Console Port PC COM Port
RJ-45        DB-9
Pins Signals Pins Signals
1    NC      –    –
2    NC      –    –
3    TXD     2    RXD
4    GND     5    GND
5    GND     5    GND
6    RXD     3    TXD
7    NC      –    -
8    NC      -    -
```

from https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/access_point/1240/installation/guide/1240hig5/124h_e.pdf

With an additional USB converter you can connect the serial to USB.

> Is there any kind of software to virtually convert a twisted pair to console?

No, that's not possible. With appropriate hardware ("COM server" or "serial server") you could connect the serial port to the network and then use a virtual COM port on the host.